# Intermittent NSTimer problem in Release mode on device

Tags: iphone, deployment, xamarin.ios, nstimer

I am having a problem where most, but not all, of the time on my device my NSTimer action is not being called when compiled in Release mode. It's always fine in Debug mode on the device, and it's always fine in either mode in the simulator.

The only thing that's slightly unusual about this situation is that it's wrapped with another class to allow us to inject platform-specific implementations of things like timers at runtime, thinking forwards to monodroid etc. Nothing particularly unusual going on though.

Code:

```
using System;
using MonoTouch.Foundation;
namespace OurCompany.PlatformAbstraction.Ios
{
  public class IosTimer : IPlatformTimer
  {
    private NSTimer backingTimer;
    public double IntervalMs{get; set;}

    public IosTimer(double intervalMS)
    {
        this.IntervalMs = intervalMS;
    }

    public event EventHandler Elapsed;

    private void NsTimerElapsed()
    {
        if (Elapsed != null)
        {
            Elapsed(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }

    public void Start ()
    {
        TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(this.IntervalMs);
        this.backingTimer = NSTimer.CreateRepeatingScheduledTimer(ts, NsTimerElapsed);
    }

    public void Stop ()
    { 
        this.backingTimer.Invalidate();
        this.backingTimer = null;
    }
  }
}
```

Calling code:

```
private IosTimer t;

public override void ViewDidLoad ()
{
    base.ViewDidLoad ();

    t = new IosTimer(100);
    t.Elapsed += UpdateLabel;
    t.Start();
}

private void UpdateLabel(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // not being called in Release mode on the phone
    // works fine in Debug mode on the phone, works fine in both modes in the simulator
}
```

I'm also noticing general behaviour differences - where something works fine in the simulator but not on the device. Also slight behaviour changes given two identical deployments of the exact same code to the same device(!)

Posted this yesterday on the MonoTouch forums but it seems a bit quiet over there.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please file a bug with a test case at http://monotouch.net/Support

Comment: Have you tried using System.Timers.Timer?  I have used it and not had any issues like you mention.

Comment: Ah, brilliant - for some reason I was under the impression that System.Timers.Timer didn't exist in the libraries available to MonoTouch. One less thing to abstract away...

Comment: @Geoff Norton - one such bug report of inconsistent behaviour on the device compared to the simulator is here: https://bugzilla.novell.com/show_bug.cgi?id=683924 (though it is unrelated to this question specifically)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Transpired this was threading related. Solved by using InvokeOnMainThread() in my Elapsed event handlers.